# Novel where human and alien work together to open a portal

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been trying to find the name of this sci-fi series for 10 years. I found the book in a share library on a Greek island, so I'm sure it's traveled far by now.

The novel was set in the future, where the Earth has been subsumed into the greater galaxies powers (so far, so standard.) The aliens ruling the Earth are giants as far as I remember.

The story focus on a human and and alien  working to open a doorway or portal. On the other side are a 'legion, of hostile aliens with crystal biotechnological bodies.'

The alien partner of the human passes through different life stages and has grown extra eyes at the conclusion of the book.

There is also the addition of an artificial intelligence that helps the human, but turns out to be a part of the enemy.

It had a blue cover featuring a classic 70-90's space ship.

Can anybody help me identify this novel or series?

Comment: Do they not know about the enemy?  Do they succeed in opening the portal?  If so, how do they deal with the enemy?  Why are they trying to open the portal?

Comment: The plot about trying to open a portal reminds me of Shakespeare's Planet by Clifford D. Simak, but nothing else fits so I doubt that's it. Some elements you describe (far future, galactic powers, biotechnology, alien entities from the other side) vaguely match the Night's Dawn trilogy by Peter Hamilton (particularly book three, The Naked God), but it's not a close match.

I have a few questions. First, when did you read this, like, which decade? Second, was it in English? Third, do you know for sure if it's part of a series or is that just a guess?